# SpringWebSockets does not send message from server

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-websocket

Hi i have an issue with spring websockets, this is the scenario:

a standalone application is sending (remote) some data like date Date, procedence String, and weight BigDecimal this data is sending via TCP to socket,

after that this data is saving into database at this point all is fine, but in the next step (websocket) i cannot show this information in a webpage, the weight data must be showed (live) in the screen

this is my websocket configuration:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolver;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.ChannelRegistration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketTransportRegistration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/indicator").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(final ChannelRegistration registration) {
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientOutboundChannel(final ChannelRegistration registration) {
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration wstr) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean configureMessageConverters(List<MessageConverter> list) {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}
```

this is my another class that receive data form socket and process information and send to websocket:

```
import com.mcss.mcontrols.helper.ByteHelper;
import com.spc.basweb.Constants;
import com.spc.basweb.transmissor.dto.Transmission;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.core.MessageSendingOperations;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.BrokerAvailabilityEvent;
import com.spc.basweb.service.BroadcastingService;
import com.spc.basweb.service.DataProcessorService;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessageEndpoint;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Transformer;

@MessageEndpoint
public class BroadcastingServiceImpl implements BroadcastingService, ApplicationListener<BrokerAvailabilityEvent> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BroadcastingServiceImpl.class);
    private final MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate;
    private String processedData;

    @Autowired
    DataProcessorService dataProcessorService;

    @Autowired
    public BroadcastingServiceImpl(final MessageSendingOperations<String> messagingTemplate) {
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public String getProcessedData() {
        return processedData;
    }

    @Override
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "broadcaster")
    public String broadcast(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            Transmission t = (Transmission) ByteHelper.toObject(bytes);
            LOGGER.debug(t.getProcedence() + " " + t.getDate() + " " + t.getWeight());
            String rm = this.dataProcessorService.processData(t);
            this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(Constants.END_POINT_READ, this.dataProcessorService.getWeighing().getWeight().toString());
            return rm;
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            LOGGER.error("Error de transmision de objetos", ex);
        }
        return DataProcessorService.NOT_OK_RESPONSE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(BrokerAvailabilityEvent e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Application event");
    }

    @Transformer(outputChannel = "broadcaster")
    public String convert(String response) {
        return response;
    }
}
```

in the debbuger i'm getting this information:

```
30-03-2016 15:07:20 DEBUG SimpleBrokerMessageHandler:277 - Processing MESSAGE destination=/read session=null payload=3003
```

in another class (Controller) i'm using the same method:

```
this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(Constants.END_POINT_READ, "3500");
```

and sending "manually" the information an is showing correctly. and i'm getting in debbuger this message:

```
30-03-2016 15:05:18 DEBUG SimpleBrokerMessageHandler:277 - Processing MESSAGE destination=/read session=dfR45V77 payload=3500
```

the difference is in session value but i don't know what this session is having null in the process, what am i doing wrong some clarification o help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't see the `configureMessageBroker` implementation, so it isn't clear how that may work at all...

From other hand if you see such a difference, try to debug the code in the `SimpMessagingTemplate`.

I only see `headerAccessor.setSessionId(sessionId);` in the `SimpleBrokerMessageHandler` when it does

```
 logger.debug("Broadcasting to " + subscriptions.size() + " sessions.");
```

Comment: hi thanks for the fast response, i don't know how to configure the MessageBroker, but you are right in the process i have no subscribers in the registry but also i dont know why, direclty from the controller i have after sending this debbug 30-03-2016 16:07:42 DEBUG SimpleBrokerMessageHandler:301 - Broadcasting to 1 sessions.

Comment: in the web logger i have this one: <<< MESSAGE
destination:/read
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
subscription:sub-0
message-id:d3jf01vk-6
content-length:4

3500
monitoring.controllers.js:12 3500

Comment: You can find how to configure Simple Broker in the Spring Framework Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-simple-broker. So, you really don't have subscribers there for that destination yet. You really can send messages only when there are some subscribers otherwise the session header is `null`.

Comment: i added those lines to configureMessageBroker: @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes(Constants.DESTINATION_PREFIX);
        registry.enableSimpleBroker(Constants.END_POINT_READ);
    } but i have no result is exactly the same, i still having 0 subscribers for this context, another advice??

Comment: Who is the client of your application? Why just don't subscribe it to the desired destination?

Comment: this. data is showing in the webpage accross angular with sockJS and stomp the content of Constants.DESTINATION_PREFIX = "/app" and Constants.END_POINT_READ = "/read" the endpoint is "/indicator"